# Set session from C# class in app code. ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to set a session but my session is always null?

This is what i have tried.

```
Session["Email"] = userName;
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Email", userName);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Email"] = userName;
this.Session["Email"] = userName;
```

Here is a look at my class.

```
public class MySessionSet
{
    public MySessionSet()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void SetSession(string SessionName, string SessionValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName] = SessionValue;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: Can you post your web.config, to make sure your `sessionState` is actually enabled.

Comment: @christiandev Could you tell me which part of the web.config you would like to see as i can't post the whole thing.

Comment: I put is as an answer, if it's incorrect, I will delete the answer.

Comment: <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>

Answer (score 1):

Check your web.config, there could be a section called `sessionState`, by default this will be set to `InProc`, but you might have it switched off?

```
<sessionState 
    mode="Off"....
>
</sessionState>
```

[MSDN Link to sessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx).

To use InProc, set it to this...

```
<sessionState 
        mode="InProc"....
    >
 </sessionState>
```

Or, if you have it to `StateServer`, make sure the [*StateServer Windows Service*](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0d9dc063-dc1a-46be-8e84-f05dbb402221.mspx?mfr=true) is running on the box.

**Side note**, this might be worth a read too: [*Think Twice Before Using Session State*](http://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/)

Comment: it looks like my session was StateServer, I changing it to SessionState.

Comment: <sessionState mode="Off" timeout="30" /> I am still getting null?

Comment: Even with the mode InPros i am still getting null.

Comment: Are you using `InPros` or `InProc`?

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />

Answer (score 0):

Try inheriting  System.Web.UI.Page to your class MySessionSet..

Comment: A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces;